# simplify multiple validation handled by single error message

Tags: knockout.js

I am using ko validation for the below observable.

```
self.phoneEXT = ko.observable('').extend({
            minLength: {
                message: "Please enter valid extension",
                params: 4
            },
            maxLength: {
                message: "Please enter valid extension",
                params: 6
            },
            number: {
                message: "Please enter valid extension"
            }
        });
```

How to simplify the above validation?

Comment: your pattern is fine, this way you can put custom error messages, if you want to join all validation together then you need to use custom validation rules.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest simply adding a 'centralized' object to store your default messages:

```
var errorMessages = {
  ENTER_VALID_EXTENSION: "Please enter a valid extension."
};

self.phoneEXT = ko.observable('').extend({
        minLength: {
            message: errorMessages.ENTER_VALID_EXTENSION,
            params: 4
        },
        maxLength: {
            message: errorMessages.ENTER_VALID_EXTENSION,
            params: 6
        },
        number: {
            message: errorMessages.ENTER_VALID_EXTENSION
        }
    });
```

Other than that, I think there's not much you can (let alone *need to*) improve...

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to do a validation with default error messages then do as follows,

```
self.phoneEXT = ko.observable('').extend({
                   minLength: 3,
                   maxLength: 6,
                   number:true,
                });
```

knockout will append default error message.